# Registered class "could not be found" Blender 2.8

Tags: scripting

I just started learning scripting. I have a pretty basic script that should create a custom operator

```
import bpy

class CustomOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Custom Operator"
    bl_idname = "object.custom_operator"
        
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None
    
    def execute(self, context):
        old = context.scene.cursor.location
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        z = 0;
        context.scene.cursor.location = (x, y, z)
        return {"FINISHED"}
   
bpy.utils.register_class(CustomOperator)

bpy.ops.objects.custom_operator()
```

but for some reason bpy.ops.objects.custom_operator() doesn't work and says that it "could not be found".

Comment: Maybe this is a typo but you should mind the "S" at the end of "bpy.ops.ObjectS" (it must be the exact same name as the operator bl_idname)

Comment: @Gorgious It works now when I put the s there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Gorgious for the answer. It turns out that I forgot the s in objects at the bl_idname.